# Why do my grid is not placed in a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a 16 x 16 grid where I can etch a sketch on that grid. It's working well. However, the problem now is that, my 16x16 grid is not hold in a container where I append it. Isn't it supposed to contain in the container where I append it ? I want to display the grid in a way like it's in a big squared box and empty on the inside. Only the most outer border is displayed. So that way, the user will know intuitively they'll have to hover over the box to sketch.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow');
let columns = document.getElementsByClassName('gridColumn');

function createGrid(number) {
  makeRow(number);
  makeColumn(number);
}

function makeRow(numberOfRow) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(row);
    row.classList.add('gridRow');
  }
}

function makeColumn(numberOfColumn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
      let column = document.createElement('div');
      column.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        column.classList.add('colored');
      });

      //  column.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      //     column.classList.remove('colored');
      //  })

      rows[j].appendChild(column);
      column.classList.add('gridColumn');
    }
  }
}

createGrid(16);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: beige;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

#setGridSize {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 12px;
}

#guide {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  color: red;
  font-size: 13px;
  ;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.gridColumn {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid beige;
  margin: -2px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}

.colored {
  background: red;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header"> Let's sketch ! </h1>
<div id="setGridSize">
  <p> Grid size </p> <input type="text" placeholder="Size of Board" class="size-box">
  <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
</div>
<p id="guide"> Enter a number between 2 to 99</p>

<div class="container"></div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="white"> White </button>
  <button id="eraser"> Eraser </button>
  <button id="black"> Black </button>
  <button id="rainbow"> Rainbow </button>
  <button id="reset"> Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it: change `height` to fixed value.

```
.gridColumn {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid beige;
    margin: -2px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow');
let columns = document.getElementsByClassName('gridColumn');

function createGrid(number) {
  makeRow(number);
  makeColumn(number);
}

function makeRow(numberOfRow) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(row);
    row.classList.add('gridRow');
  }
}

function makeColumn(numberOfColumn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
      let column = document.createElement('div');
      column.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        column.classList.add('colored');
      });

      //  column.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      //     column.classList.remove('colored');
      //  })

      rows[j].appendChild(column);
      column.classList.add('gridColumn');
    }
  }
}

createGrid(16);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: beige;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

#setGridSize {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 12px;
}

#guide {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  color: red;
  font-size: 13px;
  ;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.gridColumn {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid beige;
  margin: -2px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.colored {
  background: red;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="header"> Let's sketch ! </h1>
<div id="setGridSize">
  <p> Grid size </p> <input type="text" placeholder="Size of Board" class="size-box">
  <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
</div>
<p id="guide"> Enter a number between 2 to 99</p>

<div class="container"></div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="white"> White </button>
  <button id="eraser"> Eraser </button>
  <button id="black"> Black </button>
  <button id="rainbow"> Rainbow </button>
  <button id="reset"> Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow it works !! How did you do that ? And why is that ?

Comment: @JabriJuhinin container height = 100%, items height = 10%. You have 16 items and so its height will be 160% which is greater than the height of the container.

Comment: That makes sense. Now I got my grid in the right place. However, I can't seem to make the most outer lines to be displayed so that my grid is in a box. I tried adding border property to the container but the border is taking the full page and not embraced the grid. Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: P.S : I found a solution to this. I've added align-items on the body class in css and it goes to the center and embraced the grid.